# How do I make my Wordpress website navigation menu font larger and not capital letters?

Tags: wordpress

[the homepage menu font too small and all capital state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cwK2.jpg)

How do I make my Wordpress website navigation menu font larger? And become normal type to display but not capital letters(the site host on Bluehost)?
Thank you so much.

Comment: You can do it via CSS. `.selector{text-transform: capitalize;font-size:18px}` I have given an example of 18px you can increase it as much as you want.

Answer (score 1):

menu.navbar {font-size:14px; text-transform: capitalize;}

Answer (score 1):

First, inspect your menu text class, and then write this css code in the style.css file:

```
.selector{text-transform: capitalize;font-size:22px}
```